# Tess4j on netbeans

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

good day,

I am using Tess4j as a wrapper on java to implement Tesseract OCR.

Followed closely to tutorials and guides provided but was returned with the following errors when compiled to scan a sample image:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: The specified module could not be found.

    at com.sun.jna.Native.open(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:263)
    at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:403)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.<init>(Library.java:147)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:502)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:481)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(LoadLibs.java:77)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(TessAPI.java:42)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:367)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:280)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:212)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:196)
```

I have already add in then necessary library as well as libtesseract304.dll and gsdll64.dll into the project.

Please refer to my structure below:
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a Leptonica dependency, but you don't need to include the source files of Tess4J library as there already is JAR package for it. Check out the example in the [Tutorial](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/).